# Permanently pairing one bluetooth mouse with two Linux laptops

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, bluetooth, bluez

My goal is to use the same bluetooth mouse on two different Linux laptops without having to repair the mouse every time I switch from one laptop to the other. These laptops both run Ubuntu, albeit different versions - hence the BlueZ versions are different:

- Laptop ONE is Ubuntu 22.04 with BlueZ 5.64
- Laptop TWO is Ubuntu 20.04 with BlueZ 5.53

I have found [this article](https://averylarsen.com/posts/keeping-bluetooth-devices-paired-between-linux-and-windows/) referenced from the [Archlinux Bluetooth wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth) and concluded that copying the files under `/var/lib/bluetooth/<bt-controller-mac>/<bt-mouse-mac>` from ONE to TWO might be a solution to achieve what I want.

Hence, I created a TAR archive containing directory `<bt-mouse-mac>` from laptop ONE, where the mouse has been paired using bluetoothctl and works flawlessly. I've restored that archive under `/var/lib/bluetooth/<bt-controller-mac>` on laptop TWO, keeping an eye on file ownership and permissions. I've verified that these are the same on both machines. Note also that `<bt-controller-mac>` is of course different on the two machines. I left that directory intact and copied only the `<bt-mouse-mac>` child directory, to be clear.

It turns out that after restarting bluetooth.service on machine TWO, the mouse shows up in `bluetoothctl devices`, but its state is disconnected. Attempting to connect it manually using `bluetoothctl connect <bt-mouse-mac>` results in an error message `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed` in the bluetoothctl CLI.

I've repeated this procedure with bluetoothd running in debug mode. This shows an error message:

```
bluetoothd[8590]: src/device.c:att_connect_cb() connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

Could it be there is more to establishing the pairing than just copying the `/var/lib/bluetooth` content? For reference, here's my full content of `/var/lib/bluetooth/<bt-controller-mac>/<bt-mouse-mac>/info`, which I assumed to contain everything needed for pairing:

```
[General]
Name=BluetoothMouse3600
Appearance=0x03c2
AddressType=static
SupportedTechnologies=LE;
Trusted=true
Blocked=false
WakeAllowed=true
Services=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

[IdentityResolvingKey]
Key=6BE642E733F097057408B7E3A36F36C7

[LocalSignatureKey]
Key=82007F13D7C08609FC80B54A7FC998D8
Counter=0
Authenticated=false

[LongTermKey]
Key=AA81538D8BC708D1589D899CC206576D
Authenticated=0
EncSize=16
EDiv=41145
Rand=7412921918571674439

[DeviceID]
Source=2
Vendor=1118
Product=2326
Version=272

[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=6
Latency=60
Timeout=300
```

Comment: Unless the mouse allows multiple connections, you would have to use the same bluetooth adapter in both machines

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is so? Does the key material in `info` somehow depend on the BT host controller's MAC address or something like that?

Comment: The host controller MAC is remembered by the device

Comment: Makes sense - feel free to put this as an answer, I'll accept it.